# How to use webspy?

Tags: arp, sniffing, spoofing

I tried to spoof my local network with arpspoof from dsniff package. Everything is good, I can see sniffed packets from my "victim" in Wireshark.
Now, how do I use webspy? I've tried something like this with running firefox:

```
#webspy -i wlan0 192.168.1.XXX 

webspy: listening on wlan0
openURL(http://178.33.XXX.XXX/)
```

The  "victim's" computer (192.168.1.XXX) tried to connect with 178.33.XXX.XXX but I couldn't see anything in firefox. Is this requiring something more?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://blog.ironguard.net/2007/06/how-to-use-webspy-from-dsniff-suite.html), two things can be the cause for not getting the victim browser's mirror in webspy:

1. Firefox browser should be opened from the command-line `firefox &`, after running the webspy listener.
2. If `dniff` (the package of "dniff suite of tools" which includes webspy, dniff,arpspoof,dnsspoof, mailsnarf etc.) is installed by manually compiling the source package instead through the package manager (such as `apt-get` or `yum`), the **arp.c** source file in the unpacked dniff directory should be edited.
   The following line in the `arp.c` file should be changed from

   `strncpy(ar.arp_dev, "eth0", sizeof(ar.arp_dev));`

   to

   `strncpy(ar.arp_dev, "wlan0", sizeof(ar.arp_dev));`

   Save the file and recompile the application.